# javascript how to make an operator from string

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make an operator type of string into operator

```
<script>
  var operator        = $(this).val();  returns a string eg) + or -
  var quantity        = 5 operator 1;
</script>
```

currently i am using switch

Comment: You won't be able to do this if you have the following syntax `var quantity = 5 operator 1;` (which is incorrect), but you will be able if you have a string like `var quantity  = '5 operator 1';`.

Comment: var result = eval("5 " + operator + " 1"); // 6 if operator is + , this is working yaar

Comment: I would recommend another approach, as all answers says: `eval` is not a good way to go. Through my years of programming I have still not encountered a single problem where `eval` would be the best answer.

Comment: content is just numbers and +,- operator , its in my control , so i guess i will not face any problems in that , thanks fr your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *possible*, in a way, via `eval`, but see caveats. Example:

```
var result = eval("5 " + operator + " 1"); // 6 if operator is +
```

The problem with `eval` is that it's a full JavaScript evaluator, and so you have to be **really sure** that the content is under your control. User-contributed content, for instance, is something you have to be very, very cautious with.

Alternately, just do a `switch`:

```
switch (operator) {
    case "+":
        result = 5 + 1;
        break;
    case "-":
        result = 5 - 1;
        break;
    case "/":
        result = 5 / 1;
        break;
    case "*":
        result = 5 * 1;
        break;
    // ...and so on, for your supported operators
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast responce i am following the var result = eval("5 " + operator + " 1");  approach. it is simple and one lined

Comment: yeah content is just numbers and +,- operator , its in my control

Answer (score 1):

The absolutely most simple way would be to use a if:

```
var operator = $(this).val(); // returns a string eg) + or -
var quantity;
if(operator === '-') {
    quantity = 5 - 1;
} else if(operator === '+') {
    quantity = 5 + 1;
}
```

You could also use the `eval` function, but eval is very rarely recommended and is not really worth it in a case like this.

Answer (score 0):

No. The easiest would be to use `eval`:

```
var quantity = eval("5 " + operator + " 1");
```

but it is considered a bad practice. Eval is Evil. Not only do you have security concerns, it also slows down the execution of your code.

Rather, this approach is much better and safer:

```
var operators = {
  "+": function(a, b) { return a + b; };
  "-": function(a, b) { return a - b; };
};

var operatorFunction = operators[operator];
if (operatorFunction) {
  var quantity = operatorFunction(5, 1);
}
```